# How to copy whole directory/folder and paste in a different location in Jupyter Lab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

I’m wondering if there is any way to copy a directory/folder with its contents in a different location inside the file browser section.

I’m trying to copy and move entire directories between notebook folders in Analytics Lab but, I haven’t seen any option to make this action.

I would like to know if there is any functionality that I can implement or if this function is contemplated in future releases.

I appreciate your answers and comments.

Comment: not that I'm aware of. but you can boot up a terminal session...

Comment: as for the planned direction of the jupyter project, that's really something to ask the jupyter developers or post as an issue/feature request. See the [Getting Help](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab#getting-help) section on the github jupyterlab repo.

Comment: Hi @MichaelDelgado thanks for your answer, I already put the question there: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/12915#issue-1330342430

Comment: ok thanks for flagging that. it's really helpful if you can always link to other places you're asking the same/related questions so those of us on the answering side can read the various threads and better understand the full context. Thanks!